# How to edit page source with javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, html

I'm building a firefox extension, and essentially, I want to add in a button on the webpages on a specific site. I know that exactly where I need to make a change in the page source, and what I need to put, but I don't know how to
1. read the page source (I should be able to figure that out on my own)
2. edit the page source (I have been lurking but couldn't find any way to do it)
3. automatically update the displayed page

Also, in general, is this the best approach? the main thing is, I want to inject code seamlessly into the page. For example, the page source of stack overflow contains a section like this:

```
<div class="nav mainnavs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
                    <li><a id="nav-tags" href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
                    <li><a id="nav-users" href="/users">Users</a></li>
                    <li><a id="nav-badges" href="/badges">Badges</a></li>
                    <li><a id="nav-unanswered" href="/unanswered">Unanswered</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

What if I wanted to inject the line

```
<li><a id="nav-home" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Home</a></li>
```

And so that a home button appears?

Comment: Do you want to edit the source? Wouldn't editing the DOM be enough?

Comment: If you want to edit the page source you could intercept the response: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/ or http://www.ashita.org/howto-xhr-listening-by-a-firefox-addon/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it something like this

```
$("div.easy_editor ul").append('<li><a id="nav-home" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Home</a></li>');
```

Comment: At least you should mark that you are using jquery in your solution. Also it only edits the DOM not the source (although it's not clear if that is what OP wants).

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, it probably stems from my poor understanding of web development. How does that code even recognize the existing source code, or where to place it. Is it even possible to edit some random webpage's page source, so that your browser can will make it display different things?

Comment: @senjougahara-hitagi Don`t be frustrated ,SO is for this only to learning things from others , basically above code part append your html its a jquer function which append particular html into a portion of html take a look for here to get more http://api.jquery.com/append/